# docker apt-get multiple gets (can it be reduced?)

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am living in The Netherlands and so with each `apt-get update`, that's why I got also translations of the program to Dutch.

The trouble is that there are many gets needed to achieve a full list of packages that needed to be updated.

How can I reduce these many (apparently most are the same) gets?
I've already looked in `docker.list`, it only contains `deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main`

When I run `apt-get update`, I get this long list of gets of packagelists:

```
Ophalen:1 https://get.docker.com docker InRelease
Genegeerd https://get.docker.com docker InRelease
Geraakt https://get.docker.com docker Release.gpg
Geraakt https://get.docker.com docker Release
Geraakt https://get.docker.com docker/main amd64 Packages
Geraakt https://get.docker.com docker/main i386 Packages
Ophalen:2 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl_NL
Ophalen:3 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:4 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en_GB [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:5 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:6 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl_NL [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:7 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:8 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en_GB [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:9 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:10 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl_NL [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:11 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:12 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en_GB [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:13 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:14 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl_NL [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:15 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:16 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en_GB [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:17 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en [77,0 kB]
Ophalen:18 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl_NL [77,0 kB]
Genegeerd https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl_NL
Ophalen:19 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl [77,0 kB]
Genegeerd https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-nl
Ophalen:20 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en_GB [77,0 kB]
Genegeerd https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en_GB
Ophalen:21 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en [77,0 kB]
Genegeerd https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en
```

Comment: Edit your sources.list? But maybe you should tell us first what you are trying to do, what your Dockerfile looks like, etc... Maybe you don't need to do that apt-get in the first place (I really don't know, as I really don't know what you are trying to do).

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't said that this was the output on my docker host. What you suggests, is that the problem may be in the sources.list. But my sources.list only contains deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main

Answer (score 0):

Add the following block to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire {
    Languages "none";
};
```

And run this:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*i8n*
```